# Save a matrix line into a pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, calloc

I have this matrix, named Q:

0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0

0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1

0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1

0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0

and a pointer p dinamically allocated.

```
p=(int *) calloc(13, sizeof(int));
```

How can I copy an entire line into p?
like this: p <- Q[6][]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use memcpy() like memcpy(p,Q[6],13*sizeof(int));

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the matrix values are binary you can represent each line as an int and store 13 lines in the  array

Comment: And if I printf(p{6}) it will print this? >> 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0  I want to store a single line only...